# Pushing Solaris script output across network to Windows client?

Tags: networking, client-server, dtrace

I've got a simple Solaris DTrace script that outputs some disk stats continuously. By default, the output gets chucked to STDOUT, so I can redirect to a file to capture the data.

What I'm looking for is the ability to grab that data remotely. My initial thought was that I needed some sort of daemon that clients could connect to and just have the data streamed down at them, but I'm not really sure what the best sort of software stack / libraries to do this job are.

I've got knowledge of Perl and Python on the Solaris side, and will be using a C#.NET client. The client bit won't be a problem, as that can just connect to a remote socket and wait for data to appear. However, it's the server part that needs a bit more thought.

Any ideas / suggestions as to the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `netcat` or some `netcat` clone. Personally I like **[`ncat`](http://nmap.org/book/ncat-man.html)**. Here's an example

**Server**

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog | ncat -k -l -p 1234
```

**Client**

```
ncat 127.0.0.1 1234
```

Comment: Brilliant. Completely forgot about netcat.